# How to play with List of List of String with Javascript or Jquery using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

We're working on a big ASP.NET\VB.NET website project.
I need to populate three dropdownlists. To last two are independent of the previous ones. The population data comes from an SQL Server. I'd have no problem doing this with code-behind with post back but we don't want any PostBacks so I started to develop this in Ajax\jQuery.

Preface:

The dropdownlist's values and text are both different and tied up to the database. Server-side, the function called by the Ajax method returns a list of list of string with the values and text, i.e.

```
list[0][0] = "ID0" 
list[0][1] = "VP"
```

The list is well built and returns the right value taken from the database.

Problem:

Now I want to populate the dropdownlist from the list sent to the ajax success response and I have a hard time doing it.

Here's the ajax part of it so far

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "Projet.aspx/GetDir",
            data: "{VP:'" + dd_effort_vp + "',DP:'" + dd_effort_dp + "',Direction:'" + dd_effort_d + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                // This code works if only a simple list of string is 
                // returned from the server-side called function.
                var cars = response.d;

                $.each(cars, function(index, value) {
                        $('#<%= dd_effort_directionp.clientid()%>').append(
                       $('<option></option>').val(value).html(value));
                });
            }
```

This code works IF and only IF I have a simple list of string returned by the server side function.

Now I want to modify it to get the values from the List of List of String (in `var cars` and assign the right ID and Description to each item in the newly populated DropdownList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is returning to you a list of list of strings, that will come to jQuery via an array, whose elements are arrays.  You need to figure out/know which element of that array—which, again, will contain a list of strings—needs to go with your dropdown.  If you want the 0th array, you would do:

```
var cars = response.d[0];
```

---

Also, it looks like you're going through a lot of trouble to find the relevant dropdown lists since asp.net is giving them unpredictable names.

Consider giving each drop down a unique **class**, via the CssClass property, and then select it that way.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="dd_effort_directionp"></asp:DropDownList>

$.each(cars, function(index, value) {
     $(".dd_effort_directionp").append(
         $("<option />").val(value).html(value));
});
```